# Issues Handling rate limiting with SQS and Lamda

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-sqs

I'm have a aws lambda which is trigger via sqs. The lambda the makes a call to a downstream API. This API is rate limited, eventually I get a 429 response from them and rate limits are reset every 5 minutes.

I've tried to handle this by making use of changeMessageVisibility so;

When a 429 is encountered I;

- write the timestamp I'm being rate limited to in a database
- replay the message by calling changeMessageVisibility with a visibilityTimeout = seconds until the rate limiting ends

When I process any message I;

- check the database to see if it may encounter rate limiting
- replay the message by calling changeMessageVisibility with a visibilityTimeout = seconds until the rate limiting ends

The issue is when I'm making the changeMessageVisibility call I get a ReceiptHandleIsInvalid error stating that the receipt handler is not valid for the queue. The queue URL I'm specifying is the same queue that the message is being read from.

I've tried upping the visibilityTimeout on the queue. It was 60s previously I've tried increasing to 360.